# AWS Elasticbean Beanstalk eb ssh using private DNS names

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to use the eb cli utility ( version 3.8.7 ) to try to SSH to my ElasticBeanstalk managed instances.

The instances have only private ip addresses and I'm connected using a VPN to the VPC.

When I run the command eb ssh it's trying to connect on the private DNS domain which my local DNS can't resolve

```
$ eb ssh -n 1
INFO: Attempting to open port 22.
INFO: SSH port 22 open.
INFO: Running ssh -i /Users/dkotvan/.ssh/qa-cert ec2-user@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ec2.internal
ssh: Could not resolve hostname ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ec2.internal: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Is there a way to configure the eb cli utility to use the local ip address instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can see there is absolutely no way to tell the eb cli that you want to connect to a private ip or internal dns. The main problem is that, well, they are on a private subnet and there really isn't a way to connect without using another host that *is* publicly accessible. I was able to solve this by connecting to my bastion host that is in the same VPC as my EB environment. Using a bastion host is pretty standard practice so hopefully you've already got one! So really this is just an ~/.ssh/config problem:

```
Host aws-bastion
  Hostname xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx #bastion public IP
  User your-bastion-user
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/your-aws-key.pem
  Port 22 # or, a non-standard port if you configured it
  ForwardAgent yes
Host *.ec2.internal
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/your-aws-key.pem
  ProxyCommand ssh -q aws-bastion nc %h 22
```

Answer (score 1):

No, in April 2021, it is still not possible to configure the EB CLI to use the private DNS/IP address.  However, [aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli/issues/3](https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli/issues/3) might make it possible in the future.

On the other hand, *it can be accomplished* by disabling public IP addresses the Network settings of the Elastic Beanstalk environment. This will cause the [the EB CLI to use the private IP address as a fall-back](https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli/blob/ad4f92cf1be6fbb0d2b1e365514a6c5e5c1b144d/ebcli/operations/sshops.py#L92) (which is not obvious).

Thanks to [Dustin's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/936475/558812) for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to set up an alias in your `.ssh/config` file that looks something like this:

```
Host ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ec2.internal
  Hostname yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm using immutable deploy, on every deploy it create new instances and the ip address changes rendering the alias useless

Answer (score 0):

You can also modify `sshops.py` to use the private DNS name.  Varies by OS and version, but mine is located here:

`~/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/ebcli/operations/sshops.py`

Search for `PublicIpAddress` (mine is on line 88), and change it to read:

`ip = instance['PrivateDnsName'] #was PublicIpAddress`

It's too bad that the EB CLI isn't on Github...otherwise I'd contribute a way to do this via a parameter.

I also added a convenient alias for this:

`alias appname='eb init appname;eb ssh --region=us-east-1 appname -n'`

This allows running `appname 1` or `appname n`, where n is the number of hosts in your cluster.

Comment: AWS EB CLI is now on GitHub and this functionality is requested https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli/issues/3